# Yakuake refusing to open

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, yakuake

For some reason after the first time I restarted Yakuake seems to be absolutely dead... The F12 key now only seems to select and deselect my current application. I have tried reinstalling it from the software center, I've tried using terminal to open it and only get the message "Yakuake is already running, toggling window ..." but nothing happens. I have literally done nothing other than restart my machine and this is broken. I had Yakuake set to start on login and it's worked perfectly for ages. I am usually pretty good at sorting this stuff out myself, but I am afraid that I am at a loss...someone please help.

Comment: Try `killall yakuake ; yakuake ; yakuake & disown` - does yakuake open then?

Comment: Note you can use Xfce terminal: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/how-to-use-xfce4-terminal-06x-as-drop.html

Comment: Since you have found the solution, could you copy it into a new answer, submit it and mark it as the accepted answer?  This will mark the question answered.

Comment: @neon_overload I've copied their 'edit' answer into a community wiki question that they can accept at their leisure (I get zero rep from it while it's CW'd.)

Answer (score 2):

The following 'answer' was posted by the OP of this question:

> Turns out I'm a complete and utter moron and Yakuake is in fact working, but I am using a laptop connected to an external monitor and have extended desktop on. I had already set yakuake to open on my external monitor, but somehow that setting had changed and it was opening on my laptop, which was closed because I had forgotten I was using extended desktop. Excuse my stupidity, I'm going to go cry a little at my own stupidity now. Thanks again folks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when I reinstalled AlmaLinux GNOME. A quick fix is:

> Open `Settings` > Go to to `Keyboard` section

> Scroll to bottom and click `+`

> Type your command description and `Command` as `yakuake`

> Set your shortcut key I set to `F1`

> Done!

Now, the shortcut is working everywhere and yakuake opens up.